# why cv2.imwrite() not saving the file in the directory?

Tags: python, opencv

```
The image is not saving in the location using cv2.imwrite()

import cv2
import os
path=r'C_\Users\Romeo\Desktop\images'
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
ret,image=cam.read()
cv2.imshow("bnbnhj",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cam.release()
image_name='10.jpg'
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path,image_name),image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindows()
```

image displaying in a new tab, but the picture is not saving in the file directory

Comment: `path=r'C_\Users\Romeo\Desktop\images'` -> Your path has a `_` instead of a `:`

Comment: it probably path error

Comment: After changing _ into : , there is no change in the result

Answer (score 2):

Probably your directory doesn't exists. The `imwrite` will not raise any error in that case, sadly.

```py
import cv2
import os

path = r'C:\Users\Romeo\Desktop\images'
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
ret, image = cam.read()
cv2.imshow("bnbnhj", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cam.release()
image_name = '10.jpg'
if not os.path.isdir(path):
    print("No such a directory: {}".format(path))
    exit(1)

cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, image_name), image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```